# null or empty string comparison in java? or Something else?

Tags: java, string, boolean, string-comparison

```
if(txtValueUIT.getText()==null || txtValueDolar.getText()==null || txtValueUIT.equals("") || txtValueDolar.equals(""))
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not entered both values", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

What I try to do is to show the Error Message when the JTextFfields are empty or null. 
I am using if and it shows no bugs but when testing it it simply won't show the message when it is supposed to do it.

**It seems it doesn't perform any action at all because the code that follows in that method, when there is a value missing in those JtextFields, won't be processed. **

**The code that follows is a `setText` to another component using as parameters Strings that get the Text from the `JTextField`s**

By the way:

```
if(e.getSource() == btnRefresh) //I added the button with an action listener
refreshValues(); //this contains the code with the JOptionPane
```

Comment: .getText() never return null try system.out.println(txtValueDolar.getTExt()) to check it out.

Comment: Post an SSCCE. We can't deduce anything from those code snippets alone.

Comment: if(e.getSource().equals(btnRefresh))

Comment: thanks Shaalan that seems to improve my code style.
BTW 
I did try to read other methods and I performed some options... I am not sure if the problem is the String comparison it seems that since the String is null the method doesnt want to perform as the parsers don't get any value or something...

Comment: @JackTools.Net HOWEVER , It will Throw NullPointrException

Comment: @iShaalan then it is clear why hi says: *It seems it doesn't perform any action at all because the code that follows in that method, when there is a value missing in those JtextFields, won't be processed. *

Comment: I am not complete sure. I guess the parsers that follow> `UIT=Double.parseDouble(txtValorUIT.getText());`  `priceDolar=Double.parseDouble(txtValorDolar.getText());` made the method to stop when taking `""` or `null` values. I am fairly new and i found doubts everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a try with the following code:

From

```
txtValueUIT.equals("") || txtValueDolar.equals("")
```

To

```
txtValueUIT.getText().equals("") || txtValueDolar.getText().equals("")
```

Comment: `if (txtValorUIT.getText().matches("[a-z\\-_]+ ") ||` `txtValorDolar.getText().matches("[a-z\\-_]+ ")`
`|| txtValorUIT.getText().isEmpty() ||` `txtValorDolar.getText().isEmpty() )`
`{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ha ingresado ambos` `valores", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);`
`return;}`
This works like charm. Even null will show the dialog.

Comment: if (txtValorUIT.getText().matches(".*[1-9\\.]+.*" && txtValueUIT.getText().matches(".*[1-9\\.]+.*") 
{PARSERS, SETTEXTS} else SHOWMESSAGE //THIS IS MUCH EFFICIENT